# Volume of the intersection of two polyhedron using CGAL

Tags: intersection, volume, cgal, polyhedra

I am looking for a fast method to compute the approximate volume of the intersection of two polyhedrons. My program runs 20k iterations wherein each iteration I need to compute the volume of difference of two polyhedrons with ~100 vertices each (one of these polyhedrons is stationary, and the other changes its pose in each iteration). I require this program to terminate within a second.

I have tried using Nef_polyhedron_3, but it requires an exact kernel, and thus takes a large amount of time. Next, I tried to use  Polygon_mesh_processing::corefine_and_compute_difference, but I could not find a method to convert my Polyhedron_3 to Surface_mesh (without the use of Nef_polyhedron).

I would be really grateful if someone could help me with this problem. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [this faster function](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__corefinement__grp.html#ga240e5df984c7d44741a7031e38203dc3) from the polygon mesh processing package and then [that one](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__measure__grp.html#ga85cebf8fbc7cb8930fd16aeee2878c7e) to get the volume of the intersection.

If still too slow then you can use Monte Carlo to get an estimation of the volume, using point sampled within the static polyhedron. [This class](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/classCGAL_1_1Side__of__triangle__mesh.html) will help knowing if a point is inside or outside the bounded volume.

Answer (score 1):

For the conversion you can use the function [`copy_face_graph()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLHelperFct.html#ga2d3eb044bfe42eab566779ce32216c11)

Comment: I was able to use Polygon_mesh_processing::corefine_and_compute_difference by converting to Surface_mesh using copy_face_graph(), but it is still too slow. Is there any other faster method?

Comment: Is it possible to use [3D Fast Intersection and Distance Computation](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/index.html) to approximately find the volume of intersection of polyhedra meshes?